# Completeness of $C[a,b]$ with $L^{\infty}$, but not with $L^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, complete-spaces

I am referring to an example in Reed & Simon (1980) Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics I: Functional Analysis, p. 12 et seq.

We know that the space $C[a,b]$ is complete in the metric induced by the $L^{\infty}$-norm, but not by the one induced by the $L^1$-norm. As an example of the lack of completeness of $(C[a,b],\lVert \cdot \rVert_1)$, consider a sequence of functions in $C[0,1]$, $f_n$, given by the graph in the book ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ3oG.png)). This sequence is Cauchy in $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1$, but does not converge to any function in $C[0,1]$ as it, intuitively, converges to the (non-continuous) indicator function $I_{[1/4,3/4]}$. All of this is clear, but how does this change when we consider this in the supremum-norm instead? The only explanation I have come up with is that $f_n$ is not Cauchy in $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{\infty}$, because
$$\sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f_n(x) - I_{[1/4,3/4]}(x)|$$
is constant equal to 0.5 for all $f_n \in C[0,1]$ and only becomes 0, intuitively, for $n = \infty$, i.e. for a function outside of $C[0,1]$. Is this argument mathematically correct (in principle)? I am only starting to wrap my head around functional analysis, so please apologise any inaccuracies, inconsistencies and outright stupidities...

Comment: The argument after 'because' trying to explain why it is not Cauchy, doesn't prove that it isn't Cauchy. It only shows that $f_n$ stays away from that indicator function in the metric defined by $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. For Cauchy one needs to prove that $\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty$ remains away from $0$ for some arbitrarily large $m,n$. Let me assume that the sequence is defined such that when you take the sequence $f_{2^n}$ the base of the trapezoid has gone closer to the limit by half the distance. Then $\|f_{2^n}-f_{2^{n+1}}\|_\infty\geq 1/2$.

Comment: The last inequality you can see by computing the distance $|f_{2^n}(x_n)-f_{2^{n+1}}(x_n)|$ at the end point $x_n$ of the base of the trapezoid of $f_{2^{n+1}}$.

Comment: The argument is set of correct (needs some more detail) - the main reason this happens is that the essential sup norm for measurable functions is the sup norm for continuos one (prove that as is a good exercise) and convergence for continuos functions in the sup norm on any compact set implies uniform convergence hence the result is continuos